# Why C++ Compilation Succeed?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

As expected, C++ compilation fails with "warning: comparison between pointer and integer" for the program below:

```
int main(void) { return (int*)42 == true; }
```

But, the compilation succeeds, when the `true` literal is changed to `false`. Why?

- Confirmed for: clang-1100.0.33.12
- Unable to confirm for: g++ 7.5.0

Comment: This doesn't compile for me with any C++ [compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/81EKsn). Which compiler are you getting this to compile on?

Comment: Possibly  due to `false` -> `0` -> `nullptr` conversion sequence.

Comment: Fails with true and false in Visual Studio compiled as C or C++. `error C2446: '==': no conversion from 'int' to 'int *'`

Comment: Actually I wonder why `bool` is converted to `int` not pointer converted to `bool` in this case

Comment: Well I discussed this with a few friends,
it is the same if you do something like
```int main() {
    int x = ((int*) 42 == 0);
    cout<<((int*) 42)<<"  "<<((int*) true)<<endl;
    cout << (int*) 0 << endl;
    cout<<x<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```
This compilation also succeeds. Guess is your false was getting converted to zero and then eventually a null pointer.

Comment: Although I highly recommend that you keep types and comparisons as strict as possible.